# Java using a proportion only from a vector

Tags: java, vector

I am using Java and I am using a vector 'set' to store data, for example as shown below:[image]

This is created from a text file as I read each line and store it in an array values[]. Then I have a vector 'set' and for each line I add values[] to the vector 'set' so set looks as shown as above after all the data from the text file is read.

I need to find a way so the user is given a choice to input the amount of data he wants, for example if he enters 50, half of the vector (the first 7 lines) would be taken. Is there an easy way to do this? Since I am quite new to vectors

Comment: That's more of a matrix than a vector. And in fact, more of a grid than a matrix. What form is in, in your code? Picking the first 50% of a container because the user entered "50" is easy, but there is no context of any code in your question.

Comment: Note that `Vector` is pretty much deprecated, use `ArrayList` instead. Have a look at the `subList` function, available in the interface `List` for both. (Note that this will *not* copy the actual data - deep copies are expensive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have a vector `v`, and you have a percentage of the vector you want to keep:

```
int numToKeep = percentage*v.size()/100;
List keptItems = v.subList(0, numToKeep);
```

*Edit*

If you need to get another instance of `Vector` specifically for some reason, you can do this:

```
Vector keptItems = new Vector(v.subList(0, numToKeep));
```

Comment: The problem is currently I am using this whole vector to perform some calculations on, however, when this percentage is choosen I just need to perform it on that subset of data. So basically I need to create a vector containing those items only. Why is keptItems List? Can I make it a vector so that I will not have to change the other methods?

Comment: @user4345738 Yes you can get back another `Vector` if you must. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of subList method of Vector class

```
public List subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex)
```

This method. you can write logic for dynamically setting toIndex and you can always set fromIndex as 0.

Comment: The problem is currently I am using this whole vector to perform some calculations on, however, when this percentage is choosen I just need to perform it on that subset of data

Comment: Just store the list temporarily in an object before doing any operation on the vector

Comment: I need to perform processing on the kept items only however. Can I store those items in another vector?

Comment: Yes you can use another vector to store the content